# Codeigniter routers Google finding pages do not exist

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Google is creating broken links, the report says this:
Jul 19, 2011

http://www.therapistjobsonline.com/openings/2011/06/21/speech-language-pathologist-jobs-in-paris/texas-speech-therapy-jobs/physical-occupational-speech/blog/index.php

404 (Not found)

I am not sure if its the htaces file or the codeigniter controller messing up

In the codeigniter routes file we are using:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "content_pages";
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";

//include_once BASEPATH . "cache/routes.php";
//$routes['listings/permanent-therapy-jobs'] = "jobs/job_listings/3//";

$route['physical-occupational-speech/therapist-licensure-information.html'] = "content_pages/therapist_licensure_information";
$route['physical-occupational-speech/mission.html'] = "content_pages/mission";
$route['physical-occupational-speech/therapy-state-associations.html'] = "content_pages/therapy_state_associations";
$route['physical-occupational-speech/candidate-registration.html'] = "registration/candidate_registration";
$route['physical-occupational-speech/facility-registration.html'] = "registration/facility_registration";
$route['physical-occupational-speech/therapist-referral-program.html'] = "content_pages/therapist_referral_program";
$route['physical-occupational-speech/occupational-therapist-job-description.html'] = "content_pages/occupational_therapist_job_description";
$route['therapy-schools.html'] = "content_pages/schools";
$route['physical-occupational-speech/frequently-asked-questions-faq.html'] = "content_pages/frequently_asked_questions";
$route['physical-occupational-speech/([a-z-]+).html'] = "content_pages/$1";

$route['apply-job/([0-9]+).html'] = "jobs/apply/$1";

$route['openings/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z-]+)-jobs-in-([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)-therapy-jobs/([0-9]+).html'] = "jobs/job_details/$6";
//$route['listings/therapy-jobs'] = "jobs/job_listings///"; //All Jobs
$route['listings/therapy-jobs'] = "jobs/job_listings////0"; //All Jobs
$route['listings/therapy-jobs/([0-9]+)'] = "jobs/job_listings////$1"; //All Jobs

$route['([a-z]+)-therapy-schools-in-([a-zA-z-]+)'] = "content_pages/schools_state/$1/$2";
```

Comment: I'm confused... where does google fit into this?

Comment: google webmaster tools is finding these links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this particular rule in your route

```
$route['openings/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z-]+)-jobs-in-([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)-therapy-jobs/([0-9]+).html'] = "jobs/job_details/$6";
```

your link `http://www.therapistjobsonline.com/openings/2011/06/21/speech-language-pathologist-jobs-in-paris/texas-speech-therapy-jobs/physical-occupational-speech/blog/index.php` is obviously invalid. The link needs to end with `id.html`.

Its possible that you have some page where you generate these links and that page is generating illegal links. Google is just indexing the public pages in your website. Try using logs to figure out the source for these illegal links.

Comment: chose this for the best advice, still trying to figure it out. I have found the page(s) where the supposed bad links are created, but when I load the page I cannot find the bad link anywhere ... fml

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, what's the question?

You're trying to access the 'openings' controller, which doesn't appear to exist: http://www.therapistjobsonline.com/openings/. Either set up a controller for openings, set up a route to handle the openings, or set it in your .htaccess.